# Unexpected behavior in Multicast Bind

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multicast

I found a strange behavior using multicast in c#. I try on Windows using .net 4.0.
My application send and receive multicast packet. The code used to build socket is:

```
service = new UdpClient();
service.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
service.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, ttl);
service.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localIP, port));
service.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(group), localIP);
```

localIP is for example 192.168.1.1 (IP of PC running the application).

I made 3 test:

1. After PC reboot with network cable connected, run the application: all works fine
2. After PC reboot without network cable connected, run the application: failure with address not valid (as expected)
3. After PC reboot with network cable connected, then remove network cable, run the application (without network): all works fine. I expected a fail and not a success

In case of fail I can run a fix procedure, but in this case I can't detect the network problem in multicast socket.

Do you know what is causing this behavior?

Thanks a lot.

Just an update:
checking first if the bind address is in my current IP list I can remedy to previous problem (case 3) and fail before doing bind. But the doubt remains about the unexpected behavior.

Update2: trying with .NET Framework 4.8 and 4.8.1 and the behavior is the same of 4.0

Comment: When you say ".NET 4.0" do you mean you're really targeting .NET Framework **4.0** - and not 4.8?

Comment: yes, really 4.0, for compatibility with old versions of windows framework and also with mono for linux

Comment: _"for compatibility with old versions of windows framework"_ - I can assure you that no-one is running .NET Framework 4.0 anymore. And Mono supports .NET Standard 2.x - so you're just making anti-work for yourself, imo.

Comment: Thanks @Dai for your suggestion, I tried with .NET Framework 4.8 and 4.8.1 but the result is the same